# D3js Network Graph - Only drag fires on clicks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a network chart where I want nodes to display more information when the user clicks on them. I want the graph to also have drag/move behavior.

But I can't seem to get them both to play nice. When I have drag, it is the only one that fires and the click is ignored. If I comment out the drag behavior, then the click works as intended.

Here is my block: https://bl.ocks.org/Ognami/fe2757512bb709b22b826f0f48f9f247

I thought that the drag only pays attention to mousedown over 500ms or something, but it seems it just immediately goes to drag every time? Your thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine click and drag events, you can call stop propagation on click event.

So attaching events in your code can look like this:

```
node = node.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.merge(node)
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  loadInfo(d, i);
})
.call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended))
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/5zyk6zkd/